# Response from soap header

Tags: php, web-services, soap, web, wsdl

Even though i am very new to php soap concept, i write a program to communicate a web server using SoapClient.

This is my wsdl link:
https://es.adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServicesNew.asmx?wsdl

Service name : CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy
Link : https://es.adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServicesNew.asmx?op=CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy

I hosted my program in in an ssl certified hosting.When it run it generating a response in soap body response(**lngSerial**).I wanted to print the response value from soap header (**SoapHeaderOut**).

that is **intResponseCode,strArMsg,strEnMsg**.

Please guide me.Below i am providing the script which i am using.

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_ttl", "0");
class SOAPStruct
{
    function __construct($user, $pass) 
    {
        $this->userName = $user;
        $this->Password = $pass;

    }
}

$service = new SoapClient("https://es.adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServicesNew.asmx?wsdl");
$auth = new SOAPStruct('username','password');
$header = new SoapHeader("http://adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServices.asmx","SoapHeaderIn",$auth,true); 
$service->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
$param = array('lngInsuranceCompanyCode'=> '1','intInsuranceKindCode'=>'1','lngTcf'=>'3070858641','strPolicyNo'=>'1055385883','dtExpiryDate'=>'2016-04-30T00:00:00','dtStartDate'=>'2015-03-31T00:00:00','strChassisNo'=>'6T1BE42RG465465','strRemarks'=>'demo','strUserCreated'=>'demo');

$response = $service->CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy($param)->CreateVehicleInsurancePolicyResult;

 foreach ($response as $record) {
    print_r($record);
    print_r("<br>");
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per PHP documentation you should be able to get to the SoapHeader response object by using the low level API instead of the magic method provided by WSDL. In your case it would be

```
$response = $service->__soapCall("CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy", $param, null, $headers, $response_headers);
```

Which should store the object that you want into $response_headers variable.

**Old response:** (pertains to actual HTTP headers of the response)
If you instantiate the SoapClient with trace set like so:

```
$service = new SoapClient("https://es.adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServicesNew.asmx?wsdl", array("trace" => 1))
```

you should be able to get the Header response using the [SoapClient::__getLastResponseHeaders](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php)

```
$response_headers = $service->__getLastResponseHeaders();
```

Comment: **$response_headers = $service->__getLastResponseHeaders(); var_dump($response_headers); ** It printed like string(229) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 Content-Length: 1117 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2015 12:48:55 GMT " . How should i get the 3 header element value.

Comment: I updated my answer. My original was just dealing with the HTTP headers. If you use the __soapCall you can get the response headers even though it's not as pretty as pure WSDL mode code

Comment: Again same response is coming..Actually i am very new to this things..So can you please write me that header response script..Actually i tried many days.